# Vue ToDo List, Target parent array list item of the button that is clicked

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am having a road block here. I am trying to learn and wrap my head around vue.

I have a simple todo list that if completed = true it will display in the completed list and vice versa with incomplete.

I have added a button in each list item of the tasks array that when clicked should change to true and be added to the completed list.

I believe my problem is that the button in the li is not targeting the specific item in the array in which it belongs.

I guess I am having some trouble wrapping my head around it right now. I feel like I am on the right track but brain blocked at this point, Fridays eh? Thank for any insight.

**html**

```
<ul>
      <li v-for="task in tasks">
        {{task.description}}
        <button v-on:click="markComplete">Mark Task Complete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Incomplete</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks">
        {{task.description}}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Complete</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="task in completeTasks">
        {{task.description}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
 var fnc = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    tasks: [
      {description: 'Go to work', completed: true},
      {description: 'Go to school', complete: false},
      {description: 'Do your home work', completed: true},
      {description: 'Watch hockey game', completed: false},
      {description: 'Eat dinner', completed: false}
    ]
  },

methods:{

 //This works if I specify an item in the array but for any button clicked
 //This adds Watch hockey game to complete list
 console.log(this.tasks[3].completed = true);

 //Logs true, nothing happens
  //console.log(this.tasks.completed = true);
 //Logs undefined
  //console.log(this.tasks.completed);

},
computed:{
    incompleteTasks(){
      return this.tasks.filter(task => ! task.completed);
    },
    completeTasks(){
      return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed);
    }
}
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution. In your template:

```
<li v-for="(task, index) in tasks">
    {{task.description}}
    <button @click="markComplete(index)">Mark Task Complete</button>
</li>
```

in the script:

```
methods: {
    markComplete(idx) {
        this.tasks[idx].completed = true;
    },
},
```

What I would recommend for you is to set up an id property for each list item element and also specify `key` attribute for them:

```
<li v-for="(task, idx) in tasks"
    :key="task.id">
    {{task.description}}
    <button @click="markComplete(idx)">Mark Task Complete</button>
</li>
```

This is just a recommended practice for a list rendering using `v-for`. Anytime you have a possibility to define a unique key for a list item - use it.

You can read more about `v-for` directive and specifically about the `key` attribute at [this section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) of Vue.js official docs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help, and the resource, working like a charm. Ill give er a read.